# Cannot install graphics card drivers for Dell Latitude E5500

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, dell-latitude

Hi I have Dell Latitude E5500 (XP era) laptop on which I installed Windows 8.1 Pro.

When I installed windows it installed graphics a driver via windows update  called *Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1)*.

However I want to install a driver from Dell or from Intel. When I tried to install driver from Intel it gave an error that **This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software.**

I tried to install drivers downloaded for Latitude E5500 from Dell website which is *Intel GMA 4500MHD* and when i tried to install the installation failed with the same error message as above.

And when I check the logds it says:

```
!   Didn't find any INF's that match active hardware
IIF will NOT initiate reboot
Exit code = 0xA005
ResultCode = 40965
Name of Exit Code: DEP_HARD_ERROR
[07/09/16 20:15:31] Exit Code set to: 4 (0x4)
[07/09/16 20:15:31] Result: FAILURE
```

Anyone who can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Dell does not have compatible drivers for this model machine and Windows 8.1. I'm actually surprised Windows Updates managed to install a compatible driver on its own for you...

Comment: yeah it installed Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.1) drivers but It is not working with Blender 3d Modeling tool. Even my old Pentium 4(with just 96mb graphics memory) system can run blender but my core 2 duo(with approx. 1065mb graphics memory) can't. isn't this funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around the internet a lot I found out the Intel drivers which were working for my laptop (Latitude E5500) on Windows 8.1. I have zipped them so I can use them again also. If someone else also wants them I have uploaded them on dropbox which you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcvk312jlwaf6gs/Drivers-Graphics.zip?dl=0).